# How to start a dev container in VS Code with internet access

Tags: docker, vscode-devcontainer

I would like to try out a dev container for a Rust project. I have a Dockerfile with the following content:

```
ARG VARIANT="3"
FROM calavera/cargo-lambda

WORKDIR /home/sourcecode
COPY . .
RUN cargo lambda build --release --arm64
```

It always fails to build the container unless I specify `--net=host` at the `cargo lambda build` step because it can not connect to crates.io to download the dependencies. How can this be done with a dev container? It always fails because I can't specify the `--net=host` flag.

Thank you for your help :-)

Additional info about my system in case it is relevant:
I am running an updated Arch Linux with GNOME Wayland. I installed docker via pacman. I am using VS Codium with the Microsoft Store and installed the "Dev Container" and the "Docker" extensions. My user is in the docker group so it has root permissions.

Comment: Have you checked Dev container restriction page for hints, default settings ..., 
 https://containers.dev/implementors/spec/

Comment: I just checked it and it does not help :(